# How to mask a vector given selected entries

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
x <- c("Gpr39", "Myrf", "Gpr35", "Hspb7", "Rbpms", "Slfn2")
```

Given a desired input,

```
input <- c("Myrf", "Rbpms")
```

I want to mask out the non-input content from `x` resulting in:

```
c("", "Myrf", "", "", "Rbpms", "")
```

Notice the output must have the same length as initial vector, only those with non-input content is replaced with `""`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to check which strings are present in `x`

```
x[!x %in% input] <- ""
x
#[1] ""      "Myrf"  ""      ""      "Rbpms" ""
```

---

Or also with `replace`

```
replace(x, !x %in% input, "")
#[1] ""      "Myrf"  ""      ""      "Rbpms" ""
```

---

Or with `match` by converting non-matching elements to empty string.

```
x[is.na(match(x, input))] <- ""
#[1] ""      "Myrf"  ""      ""      "Rbpms" ""
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
x=ifelse(x %in% input,input,"")
```

Output:

```
[1] ""      "Rbpms" ""      ""      "Myrf"  ""
```

OR

We can use `is.element`

```
ifelse(is.element(x,input),input,"")
```

Output:

```
[1] ""      "Rbpms" ""      ""      "Myrf"  ""
```

OR

vectorize approach:

```
x[!is.element(x,input)]<-""
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as an addition. Avoid using `ifelse` where possible. Its slows down things significantly. (esp. when working with long vectors). `ifelse` seems to be 10 times slower than the other approaches.

- use `ronak3`, `elrico`, `ronak2`, `ronak1` or `saurabh3`
- the speeds of the above functions are comparable, so choose any you like.

here is my input:  `x[match(x, input, 0L) < 1L] <- "";x`

---

```
input <- c("Myrf", "Rbpms")
x <- c("Gpr39", "Myrf", "Gpr35", "Hspb7", "Rbpms", "Slfn2")
x <- do.call(c,rep(list(x),99999))

elrico <- function(x) {x[match(x, input, 0L) < 1L] <- "";x}

ronak1 <- function(x) {x[!x %in% input] <- "";x}

ronak2 <- function(x) replace(x, !x %in% input, "")

ronak3 <- function(x) {x[is.na(match(x, input))] <- "";x}

saurabh1 <- function(x) ifelse(x %in% input,input,"")

saurabh2 <- function(x) ifelse(is.element(x,input),input,"")

saurabh3 <- function(x) {x[!is.element(x,input)]<-"";x}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(elrico(x), ronak1(x), ronak2(x), ronak3(x), saurabh1(x), saurabh2(x) saurabh3(x), times=100)

#Unit: milliseconds
#        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#   elrico(x)  12.19008  12.55082  20.10380  16.50131  18.89640 146.30629   100  a 
#   ronak1(x)  14.65382  17.41286  23.43916  20.28819  22.42536 105.78990   100  a 
#   ronak2(x)  12.89295  13.87701  23.21046  18.76664  21.55648 100.71131   100  a 
#   ronak3(x)  11.92863  12.85301  16.85720  16.45560  17.92133  99.55643   100  a 
# saurabh1(x) 152.20484 159.11873 173.20959 162.78868 170.60385 289.57750   100   b
# saurabh2(x) 150.58224 157.72132 171.83867 162.72981 174.32689 281.26878   100   b
# saurabh3(x)  14.73980  16.27338  22.25143  20.26686  21.76195 109.68922   100  a
```

Comment: Nice comparision.

Comment: Is it possible for you to update answer? I have added vectorized approach too :)

Comment: sure, done! :-)

Comment: Great. Just one marking. The result of the benchmarking result is vary from machine to machine (I think it's obvious). Right? Bcoz I am getting the different result.

Comment: yes the key essense is dont use ifelse. Every other solution is "comparable".